# Prevent serialize property name in json

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I have two classes.
First one is:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public List<AnotherClass> field1 { get; set; }
```

And the second one is

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string subfieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

when I make object from these classes and serialize them I get below JSON from them

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "field1": [
         {
             "subfieldValue":"value1"
         },
         {
             "subfieldValue":"value2"
         }
     ]
 }
```

But I need below JSON how can I do that? Also I can't use `List<string>` for field1 type because I want to save this values to database with Entity Framework

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "field1": ["value1", "value2"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int id { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
public List<AnotherClass> field1s { get; set; }
public List<string> field1
{
    get{return field1s.Select(f=>f. subfieldValue).ToList();}
    set{}
}
```

Also you probably should maintain the common C# naming convention like `Id` instead of `id` and change the json name through attribute with whatever you like in your json.